# Jenkins errors keep switching without any code changes

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have 10 functional test suites that get executed in parallel. I create a folder for each test suite and execute it with the below command. I'm not changing anything in the code, but I'm getting a barrage of errors, I'm guessing at different points. Can anyone help with this?

```
mvn test -f functional-tests/pom.xml -DsuiteXmlFile=testng1.xml
mvn test -f functional-tests/pom.xml -DsuiteXmlFile=testng2.xml
...
mvn test -f functional-tests/pom.xml -DsuiteXmlFile=testng10.xml
```

One of the errors I'm running into is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.16.0:validate (default) on project functiona-tests: Execution default of goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.16.0:validate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.16.0:validate: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap
```

The second error I'm running into is (no tests executed):

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.692Z] [INFO] 
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.958Z] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project functional-tests: There are test failures.

[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] Please refer to /mycompany-pipelines-canary-ci/workspace/868698419/functional-tests/target/surefire-reports/testSuite for the individual test results.

[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] 
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.mycompany.digi.org.SessTest
[2023-05-18T01:53:03.959Z] [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
```

Third error:

```
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [ERROR] /mycompany-pipelines-canary-ci/workspace/-1649833041/functional-tests/src/test/java/com/mycompany/sdk/Test.java: 
[11,23] cannot find symbol
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z]   symbol:   class RiskObject
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z]   location: package com.mycompany.risk
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] 23 errors 
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] --------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] Total time:  02:10 min (Wall Clock)
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-18T11:24:51-07:00
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [INFO] ----------------------------------------------
[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project functional-tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 

[2023-05-18T18:24:54.951Z] [ERROR] error reading /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/raptor2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.12.6/jackson-databind-2.12.6.jar; zip file is empty
```

Comment: That `2.12.6/jackson-databind-2.12.6.jar; zip file is empty`. looks like the problem. Remove that file and turn on checking for checksum (https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2018/10/2018-10-13-maven-artifact-checksums-what/) ...